# Не работает WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

Пишу простейший проект с одним лишь `WebView` в `Layout`. При инициализации activity он должен открыть страницу в этом WebView.

Поначалу у меня была ошибка

> net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

я избавился от неё добавлением в манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Но после этого начало происходить нечто странное: при попытке открыть страницу андроид предлагает мне открыть ее в другом браузере:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings set =  webView.getSettings();
    set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Запускаю приложение на *ASUS MeMO Pad 7 ME176CX* через *ADB*.

Comment: В каком плане "открыть страницу"? Открыть ссылку из вебвью?

Comment: Да, открыть ссылку в вебвью.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
     @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
     }
    });
    WebSettings set =  webView.getSettings();
    set.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: как мне это использовать?

Comment: @user189097 обновил ответ